# trying to mimic var_dump in java

Tags: java, android, debugging, ide

I am very new to `Java` (and `Android` development). To debug, I want to mimic `php` `var_dump` method. So following some posts, I found and used that inside an activity (that is called when I launch the emulator)

```
HttpRequest request = execute(HttpRequest.get(URL_USERS));
            UsersWrapper response = fromJson(request, UsersWrapper.class);
            Field[] fields = response.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (int i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(fields[i].getName() + " - " + fields[i].get(o));
            }
```

I am using `intelliJ` ide, and I have no output of the `System.out` How can it be ?

Comment: try to use Log.i("TAG", "your message"); for outputting information to the LogCat Console.

Comment: also you can try to use a java profiler in the ide and see the status of the variables while running using breakpoint, i dont know if intellij have it

Answer (score 2):

Google [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is the best you can get in java. You can dump your object in a json, it works with almost every kind of java object.

Answer (score 0):

Java is **not** PHP :)
Mimicking `var_dump` is not possible since an object aren't just a `Map` of keys and values. The correct way to see all the variables of an object would be to set a breakpoint om the line where you create (or use) the object and inspect its variables in the debugger.